# Converting SQL to LINQ query when I cannot use "IN"

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert this very simple piece of SQL to LINQ:

```
select * from Projects p
inner join Documents d
    on p.ProjectID = d.ProjectID
left join Revisions r
    on r.DocumentID = d.DocumentID 
    and r.RevisionID IN (SELECT max(r2.RevisionID) FROM Revisions r2 GROUP BY r2.DocumentID) 
WHERE p.ProjectID = 21 -- Query string in code
```

This says, if any revisions exist for a document, return me the highest revision ID. As it's a left join, if not revisions exist, I still want the results returned.

This works as expected, any revisions which exist are shown (and the highest revision ID is returned) and so are all documents without any revisions.

When trying to write this using LINQ, I only get results where revisions exist for a document.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
    var query = from p in db.Projects
                              join d in db.Documents on new { ProjectID = p.ProjectID } equals new { ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(d.ProjectID) }
                              join r in db.Revisions on new { DocumentID = d.DocumentID } equals new { DocumentID = Convert.ToInt32(r.DocumentID) } into r_join
                              from r in r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where
                               (from r2 in db.Revisions
                                   group r2 by new { r2.DocumentID }
                                       into g
                                       select new { MaxRevisionID = g.Max(x => x.RevisionID) }).Contains(
                                       new { MaxRevisionID = r.RevisionID }) &&
                                p.ProjectID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["projectId"])
                              select new { d.DocumentID, d.DocumentNumber, d.DocumentTitle, RevisionNumber = r.RevisionNumber ?? "<No rev>", Status = r.DocumentStatuse == null ? "<Not set>" : r.DocumentStatuse.Status };
```

I'm not very good at LINQ and have been using the converter "Linqer" to help me out, but when trying I get the following message:

> "SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Only "=" operator in JOIN expression
>   can be used. "IN" operator cannot be converted."

You'll see I have `.DefaultIfEmpty()` on the revisions table. If I remove the `where (` piece of code which does the grouping, I get the desired results whether or not a revision exists for a document or not. But the where clause should return the highest revision number for a document IF there is a link, if not I still want to return all the other data. Unlike my SQL code, this doesn't happen. It only ever returns me data where there is a link to the revisions table.

I hope that makes a little bit of sense. The **group by code** is what is messing up my result set. Regardless if there is a link to the revisions table, I still want my results returned. Please help!

Thanks.

=======

The code I am now using thanks to Gert.

```
        var query = from p in db.Projects
                    from d in p.Documents
                    where p.ProjectID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["projectId"])
                    select new
                               {
                                   p.ProjectID,
                                   d.DocumentNumber,
                                   d.DocumentID,
                                   d.DocumentTitle,
                                   Status = d.Revisions
                                    .OrderByDescending(rn => rn.RevisionID)
                                    .FirstOrDefault().DocumentStatuse.Status,
                                   RevisionNumber = d.Revisions
                                    .OrderByDescending(rn => rn.RevisionID)
                                    .FirstOrDefault().RevisionNumber
                               };

        gvDocumentSelection.DataSource = query;
        gvDocumentSelection.DataBind();
```

Although this works, you'll see I'm selecting two fields from the revisions table by running the same code, but selecting two different fields. I'm guessing there is a better, more efficient way to do this? Ideally I would like to join on the revisions table in case I need to access more fields, but then I'm left with the same grouping problem again.

```
           Status = d.Revisions
            .OrderByDescending(rn => rn.RevisionID)
            .FirstOrDefault().DocumentStatuse.Status,
           RevisionNumber = d.Revisions
            .OrderByDescending(rn => rn.RevisionID)
            .FirstOrDefault().RevisionNumber
```

Final working code:

```
        var query = from p in db.Projects
                    from d in p.Documents
                    where p.ProjectID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["projectId"])
                    select new
                               {
                                   p.ProjectID,
                                   d.DocumentNumber,
                                   d.DocumentID,
                                   d.DocumentTitle,
                                   LastRevision = d.Revisions
                        .OrderByDescending(rn => rn.RevisionID)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                               };

        var results = from x in query
                      select
                          new
                              {
                                  x.ProjectID,
                                  x.DocumentNumber,
                                  x.DocumentID,
                                  x.DocumentTitle,
                                  x.LastRevision.RevisionNumber,
                                  x.LastRevision.DocumentStatuse.Status
                              };

        gvDocumentSelection.DataSource = results;
        gvDocumentSelection.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got 1:n navigation properties there is a much simpler (and recommended) way to achieve this:

```
from p in db.Projects
from d in p.Documents
select new { p, d,
             LastRevision = d.Revisions
                            .OrderByDescending(r => r.RevisionId)
                            .FirstOrDefault() }
```

Without navigation properties it is similar:

```
from p in db.Projects
join d in db.Documents on new { ProjectID = p.ProjectID } 
                   equals new { ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(d.ProjectID) }
select new { p, d,
             LastRevision = db.Revisions
                 .Where(r => d.DocumentID = Convert.ToInt32(r.DocumentID))
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.RevisionId)
                 .FirstOrDefault() }
```

**Edit**
You can amend this very wide base query with all kinds of projections, like:

```
from x in query select new { x.p.ProjectName,
                             x.d.DocumentName,
                             x.LastRevision.DocumentStatus.Status,
                             x.LastRevision.FieldA,
                             x.LastRevision.FieldB
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks Gert. This is very close and a huge help, thanks. However, I'm trying to select two fields from the Revisions table (which is why I wanted the join), I also need the status field from the revisions table. What is the best way to accomplish this? I've tried `Status = d.Revisions.Select(s => s.DocumentStatuse.Status)` but get an error: `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer1+<Convert>d__01[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader,System.String]`. Thanks (if I add `from r in d.Revisions` there is no grouping and I'm back to where I was).

Comment: I have got it working, but I don't think it's as efficient now I'm selecting two fields from the same table (and I may require more, hence the join). I've updated my question, please see the code I am using. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :). Out of interest, I guess the LastRevision properties are not available without having to specify another `from x in query`? It just means I end up with two `vars`, but this isn't really a problem obviously.

Comment: Oh you could put it all in one query, but since linq queries are composable (thanks to deferred execution) it is just more convenient and readable to do it in two steps. You can also do `query = from x in query...`.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I think I need to do a lot more reading!